# SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN with certificates signed by custom CA

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

In what situation does firefox raise a SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN error?

I created my own CA and certificate:

```
# create key for CA
openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 -outform pem -out ca_key.pem
# create CA
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca_key.pem -out ca.pem -subj "/C=US/L=Loc/O=None/CN=Custom CA"
# create certificate and sign it by CA
openssl req -new -key cert_key.pem -out cert.csr -subj /C=US/O=None/CN=localhost
openssl x509 -req -extensions usr_cert -days 365 -sha256 -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca_key.pem -CAcreateserial -in cert.csr -out cert.pem
```

And deployed `ca.pem` `cert.pem` `cert_key.pem` to Apache (`/etc/httpd/certs` in this case)

Apache was configured as following:

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName localhost
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/cert/cert.pem
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/cert/ca.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/cert/cert_key.pem
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

When I access `https://localhost/` I always get SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN even if I added `ca.pem` to firefox's trusted CA list

Other browsers are complaining, too

The CN field in `cert.pem` is `localhost`, which is definately the same as what I've accessed

What do I need to do to make that certificate work?

Comment: Doesn't firefox require the hostname to be one of the subject alternative names in the certificate? The CN is ignored, using the CN for this purpose was deprecated 20 years ago.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Oh I didn't know that at all, thank you for telling me this

Comment: `CN` is long deprecated indeed, names should be in the SAN extension. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172626/chrome-requires-san-names-in-certificate-when-will-other-browsers-ie-follow for example